# Modify Func for out parameter

Tags: c#

I have a function:

```
private static Response WaitForAPIReply(Func<Response> f)
{
  while (true)
  {
    var response = f();
    if (response.MISSING == "WAIT")
    {
      Console.WriteLine("WAIT");
      Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
    }
    else
    {
      return response;
    }
  }
}
```

And I call `WaitForAPIReply` as:

```
private static Response GetTestData(int a, string b)
{
  return WaitForAPIReply(() => GetData(a, b));
}
```

I want to add one `out` parameter in `GetData` and use this in `WaitForAPIReply` function. But I am unable to modify `WaitForAPIReply` for this?
I searched over web could see I can use delegate. But I am unable to fix this while passing as parameter to `WaitForAPIReply`

Comment: So you want `WaitForAPIReply` to have an `out` parameter as well? Then you want to call it like `WaitForAPIReply((out YourType o) => GetData(a, b, out o), out c);`, or what? It is not clear what your problem is? Maybe then you want to declare it like `private static Response WaitForAPIReply(YourOutFunc<YourType, Response> f, out YourType yt) { ... }`. Please indicate where your problem is.

Comment: @Jeppe, problem is I want to use data received in 'out' parameter of 'GetData' in 'WaitForAPIReply' function

Comment: Try what I wrote in my first comment. You must define your own "func" delegate type. It goes something like this: `namespace YourSpace { delegate TResult YourOutFunc<TOut, out TResult>(out TOut o); }` which you can put in a new file, `YourOutFunc.cs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to modify `WaitForAPIReply`? Notice that right now `GetData` has two parameters, but they are not used anywhere in your `f()` call inside `WaitForAPIReply`. The `out` parameter should be declared somewhere inside `GetTestData`, so that you can pass it into `GetData`.

```
// First approach
private static Response GetTestData(int a, string b)
{
    int c;
    return WaitForAPIReply(() => GetData(a, b, out c));
}

// Second approach
private static Response GetTestData(int a, string b, int c)
{
    return WaitForAPIReply(() => GetData(a, b, out c));
}
```

Comment: The second approach is confusing, and the third one doesn't compile (fortunately - there's no guarantee when and where the lambda will execute, if at all; that's not something you want with an `out` or `ref` argument).

Comment: @kapol, your solution is quiet helpful for declaring out parameter. But I want to use 'out c' in 'WaitForAPIReply' function. I missed to mention this in my question, so I am editing my query.

Comment: @Luaan Good point about the third approach. I will remove it from the answer.